# AngularJS absolute URL in $http

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am trying to fetch some external data using $http in AngularJS:

```
$http({url : 'http://my-externaldomain.com/user/tmp/test.txt' , method : 'GET'}).success(function(result){console.log(result)});
```

It doesn't work, when checking my chrome log, I can see the URL as:

```
http://mylocalhost.domain/myapp/public/'http://my-externaldomain.com/user/tmp/test.txt'
```

angularjs is adding baseurl before the actual url , that is the only error.
It looks like AngularJS adding my base url , is there anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: angularjs is adding baseurl before the actual url , that is the only error

Comment: serve your app using a server like `localhost:7300` and see

Comment: Did you try removing the http:// and simply calling //url ?

Although it should have used absolute, what version are you using? if it's 1.3 try adding the base tag to your head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
First , the URL I was fetching from MySQL had was contained with "'" marks. Removing the single/double quotation mark solved the problem of having my base url added on every request.

Which took me to another problem with cross site scripting not allowed by the browser unless the requested server has some header in its response. In the destination directory where my script is located , I added .htaccess file with :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

I also had to enable mod_headers in my apache2 server :

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 restart
```